# Store data inside long number or class instance for better performance

Tags: c#, performance, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing an AI for my puzzle game and I'm facing the following situation:
Currently, I have a class, `Move`, which represents a move in my game, which has similiar logic to chess.
In the `Move` class, I'm storing the following data:

- The move player color.
- The moving piece.
- The origin position on the board.
- The destination position on the board.
- The piece that has been killed by performing this move (if any).
- The move score.

In addition, I got some methods which describes amove, such as `IsResigned`, `Undo` etc.

This move instance is being passed along in my AI, which is based on the Alpha Beta algorithm. Therfore, the move instance is being passed many times, and I'm constructing many many `Move` class instances along the AI implementation. Thus, I'm afriad that it may have significant inpact of the performance.

To reduce the performance inpact, I thought about the following solution:
Instead of using instances of the `Move` class, I'll store my entire move data inside a long number (using bitwise operations), and then will extract the information as needed.

For instance:
 - Player color will be from bit 1 - 2 (1 bit).
 - Oirign position will be from bit 2 - 12 (10 bits).
and so on.

See this example:

```
public long GenerateMove(PlayerColor color, int origin, int destination) {
    return ((int)color) | (origin << 10) | (destination << 20);
}

public PlayerColor GetColor(long move) {
    return move & 0x1;
}

public int GetOrigin(long move) {
    return (int)((move >> 10) & 0x3f);
}

public int GetDestination(long move) {
    return (int)((move >> 20) & 0x3f);
}
```

Using this method, I can pass along the AI just long numbers, instead of class instances.
However, I got some wonders: Put aside the added complexity to the program, class instances are being passed in C# **by reference** (i.e. by sending a pointer to that address). So does my alternative method even make sense? The case is even worse, since I'm using long numbers here (64bis), but the pointer address may be represented as an integer (32bits) - so it may even have worest performance than my current implementation.

What is your opinion about this alternative method?

Comment: How bad is your performance that you really want to optimize this? Will you even see the difference. This would be my first question. Is it even worth thinking about...

Comment: The alpha beta search struggles with depth of 4 moves (5-7 sec~). So I'm trying to find ways to make my algorithm perform better, since the user can't see that the computer "think" (it's an interactive game, not a classic board).  I've started by implementing Zobrist Hash, which helped, but now I wonder if this attempts may be good.

Comment: And how is the memory footprint of the application? Watch how memory bevahes (even in windows default Task Manager) first.

Comment: @Evk I'm not struggling with memory problem, but with performance. I wonder if using long numbers will be more efficient that class instances. Anyway I'll get home and post how much memory it takes right now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to say here:

1. Are you actually having performance problems (and are you sure memory usage is the reason)? Memory allocation for new instances is very cheap in .net and normally, you will not notice garbage collection. So you might be barking up the wrong tree here.
2. When you pass an instance of a reference type, you are just passing a reference; when you store a reference type (e.g. in an array), you will just store the reference. So unless you create a lot of distinct instances or copy the data into new instances, passing the reference does not increase heap size. So passing references might be the most efficient way to go.
3. If you create a lot of copies and discard them quickly and you are afraid of memory impact (again, do you face actual problems?), you can create value types (`struct`instead of `class`). But you have to be aware of the value type semantics (you are **always** working on copies).
4. You can not rely on a reference being 32 bit. On a 64 bit system, it will be 64 bit.
5. I would strongly advise against storing the data in an integer variable. It makes your code less maintainable and that is in most of the cases not worth the performance tradeoff. Unless you are in **severe** trouble, don't do it.
6. If you don't want to give up on the idea of using a numeric value, use at least a `struct`, that is composed of two `System.Collections.Specialized.BitVector32` instances. This is a built in .NET type that will do the mask and shift operations for you. In that struct you can also encapsulate accessing the values in properties, so you can keep this rather unusual way of storing your values away from your other code.

**UPDATE:**

I would recommend you use a profiler to see where the performance problems are. It is almost impossible (and defenitely not a good use of your time) to use guesswork for performance optimization. Once you see the profiler results, you'll probably be surprised about the reason of your problems. I would bet that memory usage or memory allocation is not it.

In case you actually come to the conclusion that memory consumption of your `Move` instances is the reason and using small value types would solve the problem (I'd be surprised), don't use an `Int64`, use a custom struct (as described in 6.) like the following, that will be the same size as an `Int64`:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout( System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
public struct Move {
    private static readonly BitVector32.Section SEC_COLOR = BitVector32.CreateSection( 1 );
    private static readonly BitVector32.Section SEC_ORIGIN = BitVector32.CreateSection( 63, SEC_COLOR );
    private static readonly BitVector32.Section SEC_DESTINATION = BitVector32.CreateSection( 63, SEC_ORIGIN );

    private BitVector32 low;
    private BitVector32 high;

    public PlayerColor Color {
        get {
            return (PlayerColor)low[ SEC_COLOR ];
        }
        set {
            low[ SEC_COLOR ] = (int)value;
        }
    }

    public int Origin {
        get {
            return low[ SEC_ORIGIN ];
        }
        set {
            low[ SEC_ORIGIN ] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Destination {
        get {
            return low[ SEC_DESTINATION ];
        }
        set {
            low[ SEC_DESTINATION ] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But be aware that you are now using a value type, so you have to use it accordingly. That means assignments create copies of the original (i.e. changing the destination value will leave the source unchanged), using ref parameters if you want to persist changes made by subroutines and avoid boxing at any cost to prevent even worse performance (some operations can mean boxing even though you won't immediately notice, e.g. passing the `struct` that implements an interface as an argument of the interface type). Using structs (just as well as using `Int64`) will only be worth it when you create a lot of temporary values, which you quickly throw away. And then you'll still need to confirm with a profile that your performance is actually improved.

Comment: Your last paragraph got me thinking if it would be worth the effort to change the Nodes in my aStar implementation from class to struct. In the class form they store parent Node, g and fCost in themselves which are applied after construction. If I remove those changing variables and store them as a token in a dictionary and use struct nodes. Will this likely increase performance? I sometimes get up to a couple million nodes that need evaluating and an initial small test showed me that struct construction is 6 times faster than class construction.

Comment: The answer is: it generally depends, but be careful with many struct instances. Instantiation is fast because you need no heap. The question is: how do you store those instances? If you store them in an array, you are probably fine, since arrays are stored on the heap. Otherwise you will have millions of items on the stack. And you wont have the option to store a reference to the parent without boxing, which is so slow you better crate a class instance in the first place.

Comment: does this do boxing? Dictionary<Node,Node> childParentmap;They are stored in a heap which uses an 1d array as it's base.

Comment: This wont do boxing, but if you better not create one per node.

Comment: Huh no, one dictionary for all relationships

Comment: You might also want to set an initial capacity. The default capacity afaik is 4 and it doubles it each time it runs out. And each time this means a new array instance and a copy operation of all existing items.

Comment: I use a custom dictionary that does away with equality check as I know the maximum bounds of my inputs. Hashed Index == object: No secondary array which I have to check equality on.